# F#: Incorrect results when Seq.groupBy groups on a sequence?

Tags: f#

[Steven Proctor](http://www.proctor-it.com/ruby-tuesday-enumerable-group_by/) posted an example of Ruby's `Enumerable#group_by`:

```
["tar", "rat", "bar", "rob", "art", "orb"].group_by {|word| word.chars.sort}
# => {["a", "r", "t"]=>["tar", "rat", "art"],
#  ["a", "b", "r"]=>["bar"],
#  ["b", "o", "r"]=>["rob", "orb"]}
```

I decided to do the same thing in F#:

```
let grouped = seq ["tar";"rat";"bar";"rob";"art";"orb"]
              |> Seq.groupBy (fun word -> word |> Seq.sort)
```

... but I did not get the same results as the Ruby program:

```
seq
  [(seq ['a'; 'r'; 't'], seq ["tar"]); 
   (seq ['a'; 'r'; 't'], seq ["rat"]);
   (seq ['a'; 'b'; 'r'], seq ["bar"]);
   (seq ['b'; 'o'; 'r'], seq ["rob"]);
   (seq ['a'; 'r'; 't'], seq ["art"]);
   (seq ['b'; 'o'; 'r'], seq ["orb"])]
```

Why does `Seq.groupBy` not, well, group? According to FSI, two equivalent sequences are, in fact, equal:

```
> let a = seq ['a'; 'r'; 't'];;
> let b = seq ['a'; 'r'; 't'];;
> a = b;;
// val it : bool = true
```

Why then does `Seq.groupBy` not return the following?

```
seq
  [(seq ['a'; 'r'; 't'], seq ["tar"; "rat"; "art"]); 
   (seq ['a'; 'b'; 'r'], seq ["bar"]);
   (seq ['b'; 'o'; 'r'], seq ["rob"; "orb"])]
```

Comment: Mark, Andrey, Bartek: I sincerely appreciate your time and answers. Despite the fact that I have a *huge* professional crush on Mark right now—I highly recommend his F# courses on Pluralsight, BTW—I'm awarding Andrey the answer because I think he sneaked in first with the tidbit that I was missing: The fact that seq/IEnumerable does not support structural equality. Again, thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Seq.sort` returns a value of type `'t seq`, which is synonym for `IEnumerable<'t>`. Now, `IEnumerable<'t>` is not a structurally comparable type, so results yielded from calls to `Seq.sort` cannot be matched and grouped by.

You might add `|> List.ofSeq` or `|> Array.ofSeq` to convert `'t seq'` to `'t list` or `'t []`, which are structurally comparable.

Answer (score 2):

If you would try to check in fsi this equality:

```
seq { yield 1; yield 2 } = seq { yield 1; yield 2 }
```

you would get false. Comparison of lists is working as you would expect.

All you need to do is convert your sequence to list or stay with array

```
|> Seq.groupBy (fun word -> word |> Seq.sort |> List.ofSeq)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `Seq.toList`:

```
let grouped =
    seq ["tar";"rat";"bar";"rob";"art";"orb"]
    |> Seq.groupBy (fun word -> word |> Seq.sort |> Seq.toList)
```

Produces:

```
> grouped |> Seq.toList;;
val it : (char list * seq<string>) list =
  [(['a'; 'r'; 't'], seq ["tar"; "rat"; "art"]);
   (['a'; 'b'; 'r'], seq ["bar"]);
   (['b'; 'o'; 'r'], seq ["rob"; "orb"])]
```

The reason it's not working as given in the OP is because `Seq.sort` returns a `char seq`, which is an alias for `IEnumerable<char>` - an *object*. Two objects aren't equal to each other unless they refer to the same address; they have **reference equality**.

By turning them into lists, you get back the expected **structural equality**.